# Type backtick in shell string variable

Tags: linux, string, shell, variables, backticks

Can anyone tell me how I can type a backtick in my shell variable?

I am building a SQL query in a variable. 
The column name for that query is also a variable and i need to put it between backticks (it has to be a backtick, not a ' or a ").

example:

```
SQLQUERY="select `${columnname}` from table"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tangentially see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes around the parts containing the back-ticks, or escape the back-ticks with a backslash:

```
SQLQUERY='select `'"${columnname}"'` from table'
SQLQUERY="select \`${columnname}\` from table"
```